# I want to use my own pooling on CNN(Keras)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm making 'conditional mini pooling'.

However, applying this to Keras' CNN results in the following error:

> TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found:
> <**main**.MiniPooling2D object at 0x0000020E0BDD8B00>

it is my condition minipooling

**MiniPooling**

```
class MiniPooling2D:

    def im2col(input_data, filter_h, filter_w, stride=1, pad=0):

        N, C, H, W = input_data.shape
        out_h = (H + 2 * pad - filter_h) // stride + 1
        out_w = (W + 2 * pad - filter_w) // stride + 1

        img = np.pad(input_data, [(0, 0), (0, 0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad)], 'constant')
        col = np.zeros((N, C, filter_h, filter_w, out_h, out_w))

        for y in range(filter_h):
            y_max = y + stride * out_h
            for x in range(filter_w):
                x_max = x + stride * out_w
                col[:, :, y, x, :, :] = img[:, :, y:y_max:stride, x:x_max:stride]

        col = col.transpose(0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3).reshape(N * out_h * out_w, -1)
        return col

    def condition_min(col):
        np_h, np_w = col.shape
        out = np.array([[]])

        for h in range(np_h):
            zero_count = 0
            zero_count = np.count_nonzero(col[h] == 0)
            if zero_count > 1 or zero_count == 0:
                Temporary = col[h]
                result = np.min(Temporary)
                out = np.append(out, result)

            else:
                Temporary = col[h]
                mini = np.unique(Temporary)
                result = mini[1]
                out = np.append(out, result)

        return out

    def forward(self, x):
        # x = tf.constant(x)
        if type(x) == tf.Tensor:
            sess = tf.Session()
            x = x.eval(session=sess)

        x = x.swapaxes(1, 3)
        x = x.swapaxes(2, 3)

        n, c, h, w = x.shape
        out_h = int(1 + (h - self.pool_h) / self.stride)
        out_w = int(1 + (w - self.pool_w) / self.stride)

        col = im2col(x, self.pool_h, self.pool_w, self.stride, self.pad)  # 전개
        col = col.reshape(-1, self.pool_h * self.pool_w)

        out = condition_min(col)
        out = out.reshape(n, out_h, out_w, c)

        return out

    def __init__(self, pool_h, pool_w, stride=1, pad=0):
        self.pool_h = pool_h
        self.pool_w = pool_w
        self.stride = stride
        self.pad = pad
```

**Build Model**

```
def build_model(in_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, 
        border_mode='same',
        input_shape=in_shape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MiniPooling2D(pool_h=3, pool_w=3, stride=1))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten()) 
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='rmsprop',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I tried to solve this problem for a few days but I couldn't.

It's my first time using Stack Overflow, so I'm not good at matching the format, but I'd like to ask for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you do not subclass the `Layer` class from `Keras`.

Have a look at this example (from the official documentation):

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models

So you will have to implement something like:

```
    from tensorflow import keras
    class MiniPooling2D(keras.layers.Layer):
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

But I am using "tensorflow 1.x" and the difficulty also seems to be too high level for me :(

Comment: Thanks to you, I applied my pooling to keras.
Thank you again.

Comment: When someone answers your question and it solves your problem, it is common to upvote/accept the answer of the person. Though at your reputation cannot upvote, since it solved your problem please accept my answer as the solving one.